# How to post when post location expects data in array?

Tags: php, post, multidimensional-array

I am trying to post data to a website through a **scraper** that has the following input fields:

```
<input type='text' name='object[name]'>
<input type='text' name='object[id]'>
<input type='text' name='object[location]'>
```

Theoretically, if I were trying to post, I would post using `name`,`id`, and `location`, as parameters in my POST, but this isn't working (as expected).

There is a static number of fields, so I don't have to worry about that changing, but how can/can I do this?  Do I need to post using a post body?  Because there is another field that I am posting to that doesn't use `object[]`, but just a simple `name` value.

Any help appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're values will be available as:

```
$name = $_POST['object']['name'];
```

use

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

to see all data you received from the client.

Later edit:

To post such data, create an array and the use http_build_query to encode the data in a string that can be sent via the network with cURL.

```
$array = [
    'object' => [
        'name' => 'foo',
        'id'   => 'bar',
        'location' => 'foobar'
    ]
];

$post = http_build_query($array);
// send($post);
```

Comment: I think what the asker is asking is how to post the values.  @user22138 correct me if I'm wrong, though.

Comment: @motanelu thanks for your answer!  @user1947561 is right, though.  For example, if I want to cURL post the page with a PHP class, how would I do that?  Or if I'm using hurl.it (a curl client website tester), how do i test that?  If I'm just curl posting, can I make an array variable, like `$object = array();  $object['id']=test` and then post it?

Comment: I've added an edit. Sorry, I didn't understand what was requested.